# How do I push from one navigationcontroller to multiple viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-6.2

I am stacked with one prob.

[image]

This is my storyboard. How can I manage this case ? Should I use seperate navigationcontroller for each of them or just one is enough ? Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there but not quite. Put your navigation controller in front, and all the others down the line will inherit the navigation. Navigating forwards and backwards is all done for you.

[image]

Comment: Exactly! It was the mistake that I made. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UINavigationController for each usercase. You can inherit UINavigationController for all this controllers to determine same behaviour.